# How do I generate count for 1s and 0s for a particular year?

Tags: r, dataframe, analytics

[image: Dataframe]

[image: Sample table i want to generate]

I want to generate how many1s and 0s occur for each year say 2017,2018 and 2019.

Comment: Are you just asking how to do  `sum(my_array$paying_customers ==0)` ?    I think you will benefit by  reading R-introductory tutorials

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can copy/paste into R for testing.

Comment: `dplyr::count(df, Year, paying_customers)` will give the number of 1's and 0's for each Year.

Answer (score 1):

```r
quux <- data.frame(year = c(rep(2017, 5), rep(2018, 4)), paying = c(0,0,1,0,2,0,0,1,1))
quux
#   year paying
# 1 2017      0
# 2 2017      0
# 3 2017      1
# 4 2017      0
# 5 2017      2
# 6 2018      0
# 7 2018      0
# 8 2018      1
# 9 2018      1

table(quux$year, quux$paying > 0)
#       
#        FALSE TRUE
#   2017     3    2
#   2018     2    2

addmargins(table(quux$year, quux$paying > 0), 1)
#       
#        FALSE TRUE
#   2017     3    2
#   2018     2    2
#   Sum      5    4
```